# Get objects using reference in function desynchronization

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I would like to get Comments from RealTime Database. i did accomplished the task but Objects will display only after comeback to page(not refresh).

default angularfire2 constuctor inside blog.service.ts

```
constructor(public afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {}
```

My function to get comments out of DB. This is just one of many functions, I have no idea how to get reference or objects in one procedure, co i came up with function like this.

```
getComments(blogTitle: string) {
    const blogsRef = this.afDb.database.ref('blog-pl');
    let commentsRef = null;
    blogsRef.orderByChild('title').equalTo(blogTitle).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasChild('comments')) {
        commentsRef = snapshot.child('comments').ref;
      }
    });
    return this.afDb.list<Comment>(commentsRef, ref =>
      ref.orderByChild('timestamp')
    ).valueChanges();
  }
```

Of course i want get Observable Comment[], but instead i get null. Problem is that commentsRef cant get in

```
this.afDb.list<Comment>(commentsRef,...
```

before it returns values. I've tried return it inside function where i assign reference to commentsRef. But it calls 
Error:(56, 9) TS2347:Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.
Which I am not able to resolve.

trying to get it in comments.component.ts

```
public currentComments: Observable<Comment[]>;

constructor(private blogService: BlogService, private authServicec: AuthService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentComments = this.blogService.getComments(this.blogTitle);
    this.currentComments.subscribe(val => {
      if (val.length != 0) {
        this.areAnyComms = true;
      }})
  }
```

Displaying it in html using

```
<ul *ngFor="let curUserReview of (currentUsersReviews | async)?.slice().reverse()">
```

Waiting for your advices and thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it inside your first get, because data comes asynchronous. Try

```
getComments(blogTitle: string) {
const blogsRef = this.afDb.database.ref('blog-pl');
let commentsRef = null;
return blogsRef.orderByChild('title').equalTo(blogTitle).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasChild('comments')) {
    commentsRef = snapshot.child('comments').ref;
    return this.afDb.list<Comment>(commentsRef, ref =>
      ref.orderByChild('timestamp')
    ).valueChanges();
  }
});
}
```

Comment: As I said, it couse  TS2347:Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments error.

Comment: try adding type to your function `getComments(blogTitle: string):Observable<Comment> {...}`.

Comment: unfortunately still not working(wrong types of objects). is there any other option that i can get those objects?